# nested Promise & reject

Tags: node.js, mongodb, promise

I have some problem with promise functions, my app has this structure:
- routes
- service
- db

db is a class initialized when the application start and where I created some wrapper function for insert/find/ecc..., service is a layer between the route and db, here I do most of the work. My problem is that with the code below if a user already exist I want to throw an error or reject the promise but when I try to do something like this I get

> Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

where is the error?

This is my resource:

```
router.put('/', (req, res, next) => {
  bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10)
    .then(function (hash) {
      req.body.password = hash;
      service.addUser(req.body)
        .then((user) => {
          return res.json(user);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          return res.json(err);
        });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      return res.json(err);
    });
});
```

This is the service:

```
  getBy(query) {
    return this.mongo.find(query);
  }

  addUser(data) {

    if(!data.email) {
      return Promise.reject('email_missing');
    }

    const self = this;
    self.getBy({ email: data.email })
      .then((user) => {
        if(user.length) {
          return Promise.reject('user_exist');
        }
        return self.mongo.insert(data)
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        return Promise.reject(err);
      });
  }
```

and this is the db connection:

```
  find(query) {
    const self = this;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      self.collection.find(query).toArray((err, res) => {
        if (err) {
          self.logger.info('Mongo::find error', err);
          reject(err);
        } else {
          self.logger.info('Mongo::find', query);
          resolve(res);
        }
      });
    });
  }

  insert(data) {
    const self = this;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      self.collection.insert(data, (err, res) => {
        if (err) {
          self.logger.info('Mongo::insert error', err);
          reject (err)
        } else {
          self.logger.info('Mongo::insert', res);
          resolve(res)
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `addUser` function does not return a Promise. The code should look like this:

```
addUser(data) {

  if (!data.email) {
    return Promise.reject('email_missing');
  }

  const self = this;
  return self.getBy({
      email: data.email
    })
    .then((user) => {
      if (user.length) {
        return Promise.reject('user_exist');
      }
      return self.mongo.insert(data)
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      return Promise.reject(err);
    });
}
```

The `.catch` block here does not make sense because it just contains `return Promise.reject(err)` so you can remove it:

```
addUser(data) {

  if (!data.email) {
    return Promise.reject('email_missing');
  }

  const self = this;
  return self.getBy({
      email: data.email
    })
    .then((user) => {
      if (user.length) {
        return Promise.reject('user_exist');
      }
      return self.mongo.insert(data)
    });
}
```

In the router you also have to return the Promise in the `.then` and you can remove one `.catch` block:

```
router.put('/', (req, res, next) => {
  bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10)
    .then(function(hash) {
      req.body.password = hash;
      return service.addUser(req.body) // return the Promise ehre
    })
    // the then can be move out here, to avoid nesting
    .then((user) => {
      return res.json(user);
    })
    // only on catch is required
    .catch((err) => {
      return res.json(err);
    });
});
```

An additional note, you should always reject with a real error. So it would be better to write, `Promise.reject(new Error('user_exist'))`

Answer (score 0):

Nesting promises is an anti-pattern.

See item #2 in [Promise Patterns & Anti-Patterns](http://www.datchley.name/promise-patterns-anti-patterns/)

It's considered an anti-pattern because it reduces understandability and overly complicates the call stack making debugging (more of) a nightmare.

So rather than:

```
bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10)
    .then(function (hash) {
      req.body.password = hash;
      service.addUser(req.body) // ANTI-PATTERN
        .then((user) => {
          return res.json(user); // [1]
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          return res.json(err); // [2]
        });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      return res.json(err);
    });
});
```

Do this instead:

```
const SALT_ROUNDS = 10

app.get(URL, function(req, res) {

  function setHashedPassword() {
    // TODO first test for existence of password in req.body
    return bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, SALT_ROUNDS)
      .then(hash => req.body.password = hash)
  }

  function addUser() {
    return service.addUser(req.body)
  }

  Promise.all([ setHashedPassword(), addUser() ])
    .then((results) => {
      const user = results[1]
      res.json(user)
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      res.json(err)
    })
})
```

Note that, at [1] and [2] in the OP's code, it makes no sense to `return` anything since there is no active context to which you can return a value.

I'd also respond with an object like:

```
res.json({ok:true, user:user})
```

and

```
res.json({ok:false, error:err})
```

So you can check for success or failure in the client.

Yes, I know you might believe that `ok` is redundant here, but it's good practice to standardize on a single result value so you don't have to  first test for the existence of `error` before you check for the existence of `user`.

Comment: I'd be very interested to know why this was down-voted?